# Will the creator of a Stack Exchange proposal become that website’s admin?

Tags: support, moderators, site-proposal

After reading the FAQ for Stack Exchange, I'm unclear on the following point. If I create a proposal for a Stack Exchange website, will I become its administrator and be able to select moderators?

This is important to me so that I can help establish a good community and maintain the website's integrity. If, as it seems to me, the answer is no, then what might be a good alternative to Stack Exchange with that feature?

Answer (score 5):

If you want an alternative, look at [THE OPEN SOURCE Q&A SYSTEM](http://www.osqa.net/).

Comment: Wow, that screenshot makes it look just like Stack Overflow.

Comment: @George: Just a coincidence, I'm sure ;)

Comment: The about page says _OSQA is originally based on CNProg, an excellent Chinese Q&A web application written by Mike Chen and Sailing Cai._ Now, have you seen cnprog? @George

Comment: @Amarghosh Yes; and the UI looks very similar to Stack Overflow.  I'm not disputing where it comes from, I'm saying there may be some sort of infringement going on because the look and feel is so similar.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/migration-of-se-1-0-sites/):

> - Sites are owned by Stack Overflow Inc. There is no co-ownership of sites, commercial relationships, or revenue sharing.

- SE 2.0 sites are run by the community. We will make every effort to accommodate former site owners’ wishes to moderate the early site but no special relationships, like appointing someone Administrator of the site for life, will be considered.
- Sites will be installed and run on the Stack Exchange Network using the SE 2.0 software. We will make every effort to maintain much of the original site name/design but we may need to make changes in the design to accommodate the SE 2.0 branding and functionality.
- SE 2.0 sites will be expected to maintain the minimum traffic criteria or be shut down.

Althought this is covered in the migration of 1.0 sites this is the standard for all 2.0 sites.

Answer (score 1):

I *suspect* it will work similar to the existing SOFU sites:

- the site will be administered by the StackExchange team
- initially, the site will be moderated by the StackExchange team
- once a user base has been established, nominations for moderators will be held based on respected users of the site with a proven good track record

If you want to become a moderator, you will need to contribute to the site and gain some level of trust first. I doubt you would ever be an administrator, as they have more powers than moderators and (I believe) can alter the configuration of the site.

This approach would make sense, as each step requires trust by the system.

I am only speculating though.