# Has the Stack Exchange buying option been closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, so-enterprise

Can I still buy from Stack Exchange to create a site like mathoverflow.net for local intranet use?

I think this option has been removed, just want to confirm. What are the other options that I have?

Comment: Options closed. New options: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

Comment: Okay, so there never was an option to completely own the site yourself? Something like pay the one time fee and then handle everything yourself.

Comment: no, such an option was never available. The code is not available, StackExchange would still have been hosting and running the application themselves.

Comment: Options on options: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57644/will-the-creator-of-a-stackexchange-proposal-become-that-websites-admin/57646#57646

Comment: devinb, for local intranet use, Stack Overflow Entperprise is available for internal use. See [Is Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow available for private or internal use?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-stack-exchange-stack-overflow-available-for-private-or-internal-use)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[The Stack Overflow Enterprise is now available!](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise)**