# Can Stack Exchange be customized to specific projects?

Tags: discussion, licensing, source-code, so-enterprise

We are a NGO looking for something 99% similar to Stack Overflow for analyzing and suggesting improvements in legislation.

I have tried searching for terms and conditions for getting Stack Overflow engine for sort of semi-internal use, and after much searching I by accident found this reply ( [Has the Stack Exchange buying option been closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60680/has-the-stackexchange-buying-option-been-closed) ).

The default answer that crops up all over the place is [Is Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow available for private or internal use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stackoverflow-engine-available) which doesn't actually say much, and the Stack Exchange site itself doesn't, at first glimpse at least, say anything about creating your own SE sites anymore, just lists the existing sites.(Or do I need to be logged in to see that option?)

Anyway, our needs are with several exceptions to how Stack Exchange sites generally work:

1. The Question part would be actually a suggestion from an expert for a change in legislation, so initially at least, no questions from people with no rep;
2. Initial majority of comments would be limited to the experts and such members that have received high enough ratings;
3. There should be possibility to limit the visibility of suggestion for the public until it is approved (received high enough upvotes from experts);
4. The site must be customizable in appearance *and* in language (need ability to supply different language for labels & help texts).

Now, it seems SO engine might be able to do this(?), but this is, of course, not how SE sites work. Any solutions available?

Comment: You may want to shoot an email to `team@stackexchange.com`.  They would better be able to answer your question.

Comment: This question seems to be closer to your issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions . Perhaps you could take advantage of one of the numerous clones: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953

Answer (score 6):

### Enterprise/Internal Q&A Sites:##Update:

[**Stack Overflow Enterprise is now available**](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise) for internal use for large organizations to build knowledge sharing communities around their own proprietary and internal knowledge.  You can learn more about Stack Overflow Enterprise on our [business site](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise).

### Public Q&A Communities:

Public-facing sites are created through the democratic, community-driven process at Area 51. You can read about that process here: [**Area 51 FAQ**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of (free!) [clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) of the engine you could try.  But be warned that what really makes this work is the active, involved, and extensive community of existing users.  As an NGO, if you have a large enough membership you might be well-situated to make this work if you can drive adoption among your members.  But more often sites end up succumbing to something we call the "Empty Restaurant Problem" - no one goes there because there's not anyone there yet.