# Buying a Stack Overflow License

Tags: discussion, licensing, technology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Stack Exchange be customized to specific projects?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66689/can-stack-exchange-be-customized-to-specific-projects)

We were interested in using Stack Overflow's technology on our website and heard that you have to purchase a licenseto do this?

Is this true?

Comment: I would purchase a licence if I needed to support/faq site.

Answer (score 5):

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66689/can-stack-exchange-be-customized-to-specific-projects) by [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino):

> We no longer offer a subscription service nor license the software to
>   host Stack Exchange sites. Stack Exchange sites can only be created
>   through the democratic, community-driven process at Area 51. You can
>   read about that process here: [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).
>
> We do not offer “white-label” services, nor the ability to bypass Area
>   51 to create sites through partnerships.

Comment: The answer you're citing is... not _necessarily_ accurate. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions/96031#96031 Also, boo for posting an answer here instead of flagging as a duplicate.

Comment: @PopularDemand, even if the answer was the same, the question didn't much look the same to me. I'll know better next time.

Comment: We sometimes close things on MSO as duplicates that aren't really duplicates, but in this case I thought the resemblance was pretty clear. This question is just... very generic.

Answer (score 3):

Check out some open source alternatives instead of spending some money on a license.
 [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) meta link has  a lot of info.

I've personally tried OSQA and tell you that it is very easy to setup and implement!
Give it a shot!

Comment: OSQA is the only viable one that I've seen.