# Selling/licensing Stack Overflow platform for use in private companies

Tags: discussion, licensing, collaboration, so-enterprise, private-site

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow available for private or internal use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available)

I love what Stack Overflow did with Facebook to allow Facebook developers to collaborate, share, and solve problems together in an open environment.

The Stack Overflow platform itself is absolutely great. I work for a private company, and all of our documentation is handled with an in-house wiki. But when it comes to asking questions or researching bugs and issues, you are left to your own devices or you simply have to find the right person in the company to talk to and call/email them.

We are not a small company. We have about 4000 employees in over seven buildings.

The software my company creates is proprietary, so unfortunately, we can't be part of this open source community in the same fashion that Facebook is.

Would Stack Exchange ever think about selling or licensing their platform to be leveraged inside of private companies looking for a better way to solve problems and collaborate on issues?

Comment: and also related: [Can Stack Exchange be customized to specific projects?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66689/182513)