# Marked as a duplicate, but of what?

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60680/242209) has been closed as a duplicate, but does not link the dupe target on the question.  I have no navigate to the post's [edit history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/60680/revisions) to see the dupe target.

[image: Duplicate question, no links to dupe target]

Comment: Wow, [status-completed] 2 minutes after posting.

Comment: @Gothdo That's what you see when someone proposes a feature that existed before they proposed it.

Comment: @Servy But this is tagged [bug], not [feature-request].

Comment: @Gothdo So then replace "feature request" with "bugfix" in my last comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Back in the good ol' days, when a question was closed as a duplicate, the link(s) to the original were inserted into the post as a revision. As a side-effect, they could be edited out... which is exactly what happened here (I presume by accident).

I rolled back the edit and re-did the valid changes, so the links are on display again.

Comment: That's on me, then. I was under the mistaken impression that the "new style" duplicate message would be displayed instead. Lesson learned.

Comment: @AʟE. No worries. The change wasn't retroactive for a variety of reasons, so it takes reopening/reclosing the question to get the new banner to display.